# Copy data from "SELECT Multiple" Selection Box

Tags: html, database

I need to copy data from a selection box with the "multiple" HTML attribute that looks something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple):

[image: EXTRACT FROM OP's image]

I have tried selecting all options and do "Ctrl-C" but it didn't work. When I go to the source, I can get the data but there is no way to filter out the HTML codes that goes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

Copy all the **option** tags (see above) from the HTML source (you'll find them between **select** tags) and paste into Notepad++, then search/replace as follows with the **Regular expression** option selected:

[image: 1]

**Find what:** `<option.*?>(.*?)</option>`
**Replace with:** `\1`

You can also use Microsoft Word to search/replace as follows with the **Use wildcards** option selected:

[image: 2]

**Find what:** `\<option*\>(*)\</option\>`
**Replace with:** `\1`