# How to copy the text displayed in an HTML dropdown list (<select>)?

Tags: html, firefox-extensions

I'm looking for a tool that surely must exist somewhere...

There's a dropdown list on a webpage with numerous values in it. I simply want to copy these values into the Windows clipboard and paste them into a text editor with one value per line.

Am aware this can be done using Firebug followed by a bit of complex search-and-replacing or alternatively perhaps a few lines of Javascript but there must surely be an easier way using a couple of clicks of the mouse. Don't want to reinvent the wheel!

Has anyone come across a Firefox Extension, Greasemonkey User Script or similar that already does this?

Comment: Also see: [Copy data from "SELECT Multiple" Selection Box](http://superuser.com/questions/536810/copy-data-from-select-multiple-selection-box).

Comment: Reposted on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/77704/903 since it is closed here + the accepted answer is 404

Comment: Thanks @FranckDernoncourt. Looks like it was removed from the web store. Not sure if an alternative exists but couldn't easily find one so in the meantime have changed the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about a script, and it may be a bit more work than you're interested in, but you can select the object and hit "Inspect Element" which will tell you where the dropdown is in the code.  Then, right click on the "select" area that is the dropdown, and hit "copy as HTML".  Then you can paste it to a text editor of your choice.  It will require some manual cleanup.

This is by no means an optimal solution.  But it is the best I have at hand.

Comment: Yes - that was the kind of thing I meant by "using Firebug followed by a bit of complex search-and-replacing". The search-and-replacing ain't trivial but I've just worked out it can be done using the following regular expression in Notepad++: `\s*</?option.*?>` Bit fiddly but the best I've got so far so thanks.

Comment: I know it is, bu no means an optimal answer.  But since I have plenty of time on my hands, sometimes the sub-optimal solutions are "enough".  Would be nice to have something more integrated.  But, then I'd probably rarely use it, making it something that might not be worth the time to install it.

Comment: +1. I don't think there is faster solution. Actually "inspect element", copy HTML, then replace the html tags with empty string => effectively leaving only the values requires less than a minute.

Comment: Less than a minute's good and the best I've got so far...still think a few seconds would be better.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free add-on for Google Chrome that serves exactly this purpose.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-html-list-options/amoeofpgnollolnonakakmiehlanaocl/related

Comment: Works quite well. Right-click anywhere on the page, select "Export HTML List Options" -> "Displayed Text" then scroll down to the relevant dropdown and select / copy the text. (I couldn't immediately see a way of narrowing the results down to a single dropdown.)

Comment: "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this problem, you can right click on the dropdown, and Inspect Element. Right click on the selector and choose "copy inner html". Open up Microsoft Word and paste your contents in. Select All and Go to Table -> Convert -> Convert Text-to-table (or Insert -> Table ->Convert Text-to-table). 3 Columns, and choose " as the delimiter - this will give you the option value in its own column. Select the column with your text, paste into a new Word doc, then go to Table -> Convert -> Convert Table to text (or Layout -> convert table to text). Separate Text with Paragraph Marks worked for me.

You can mess around with it if you need the actual dropdown text- it just takes some extra steps if your delimiter is different.